# I need help incorporating my design into Azure.

Tags: architecture, azure, azureservicebus

[image]

I'm guessing I want to use some version of the Azure Service Bus in front of all the server side processing (Scrubbing, Augmenting, Social Profiles and Email Notifications).

The documentation on the Azure Service Bus is extremely cryptic to me and I'm hoping someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving all that processing out of your web roles is definitely a good idea. Service Bus queues would certainly work. Another options would be using [Azure Storage queues](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/queue-service/) instead. You may find them easier to understand, as they're a relatively straightfoward implementation of queuing concepts over HTTP and the .NET client libraries are pretty good. I believe they tend to be cheaper as well.

There are a lot of ways to break up that background processing as well. You could:

1. Use your web roles as workers, by spinning up worker threads in the WebRole.Run() method to do the work.
2. Have a single worker that does all the stages in a row.
3. Have a single worker that does all the stages separately, with another queue in between each stage.
4. Have multiple workers, or even multiple workers per stage.

Depending on how resource intensive the work is and how quickly it needs to be done, one approach may be better than the others. More intensive processing would tend to lead you further down that list.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how complex this project/product is and how many transactions your have...but as you mention you could use the Service Bus Queue to:

1. receive the messages and temprorarily store them in a FIFO queue
2. pass them to a specific function worker role: "scrub contacts" worker role
3. pass messages back to queue/storage

What is nice about that is you could have one worker role that does 4 specific tasks: scrub messages, augment data, pull social profiles, email notifications.  You can select the functionality based on the message.

You can have one message go to the queue, queue passes is it off to the worker role telling it "scrub messages", pass back to the queue, queue passes it it off to the worker role "augment data" etc.

OR you can have a service bus queue and do "scrub messages, augment data, pull social profiles, email notifications"...etc

The beauty of this is that the Service Bus queue manages the FIFO traditional messaging functionality.  Furthermore, you have a loosely coupled system of worker roles that can be scaled dramatically to increase message processing as needed.